# PHP echo with if not working

Tags: php, html

I am learning PHP and my `echo` is echoing wrong data.

```
 $user_post=4;

 if($user_post=5){ 
    echo "User has 5 posts."; 
 }else{
    echo "Cannot continue! Not enough posts: $user_post"; die(); 
 }
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: `=` is assignment operator (for setting a variable value), `==` or `===` are comparison operators

Comment: use `==` to check for equality

Comment: Assignment !== comparison

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your if is not correct.
You must use **==**, not = to check if somethng equals in PHP.

```
if($user_post==5)
```

Comment: thank you it was the probelem

Answer (score 2):

You have to use comparison operator: equal `==` (same value) or identical `===` (same value and same type).

You can explore php manual for learning http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

```
if($user_post=5)
```

this is assignment operator each time it will assing 5 to $user_post varibale change your operator to

```
if($user_post == 5)
```

or

```
if($user_post ==== 5)
```

The difference is frist one will check value only and 2nd one will check its type
I hope it will help you